# Convert array to dataframe columns

Tags: python

As array shown below, i want convert into two pandas datarame columns so that i can send to csv file.

I tried using different function like concat, to_array, but didn't help.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanking in advance.

```
array([2.47286323, 2.59804292, 3.14455557, ..., 1.6698064 , 1.29305288,
   1.06400106])

array([2.47496667, 2.62663333, 2.8342    , ..., 1.57346667, 1.65933333,
   1.1637    ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array1 = np.array([1, 2])
array2 = np.array([3, 4])
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"column1":array1, "column2":array2})
```

Answer (score 0):

exan`s answer is already sufficient. Nevertheless a different way would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([2.47286323, 2.59804292, 3.14455557, 1.6698064, 1.29305288, 1.06400106])
a2 = np.array([2.47496667, 2.62663333, 2.8342, 1.57346667, 1.65933333, 1.1637])

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["col1"] = a1
df["col2"] = a2
```